# preg_match returns nothing

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the wheather data from http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Berlin/forecasts/latest

but preg_match just returns nothing

```html
<?php

$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Berlin/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('/3Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents, $matches);




print_r($matches)


?>
```

Comment: To start it is `3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:` not `3Day Weather Forecast Summary:`. You should look into using a parser though, and/or a weather API. Here's one I've used, http://apidev.accuweather.com/developers/.

Comment: Try DOMDocument instead. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is very difficult to get right and resulting code is hard to maintain.

Comment: @choz You can read url using `file_get_contents`

Comment: @chris85 My bad.. It turns out to be working just fine..

Comment: Obligatory link to [Please don't use regex for markup languages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use** a regex to parse html, user an html parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php),

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Berlin/forecasts/latest");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query('//span[contains(@class,"phrase")]') as $phase)
{
    echo $phase->textContent; 
}
```